# SharePoint 2013 People and Groups missing from Site Settings

Tags: permissions, central-administration

I'm trying to access People and Groups from Site Settings in the root of my site collection but it doesn't appear in the options (In fact most of the options are missing)

I fear that one of our other users has messed with the permissions while clicking around trying to solve another problem.

I am a farm admin. Is there a way to restore my permissions from central administration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Central Administration, follow the Application management link and select *Change site collection administrator*. Change to your site collection and set yourself as site collection administrator (primary or secondary doesn't matter). Being a Farm Admin doesn't automatically give you all the permissions on site collection level.

Direct URL: `http://<CentralAdminName:port>/_admin/owners.aspx`